# NiFi: parse json list

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I have a json file, some attribute will be a list. But not sure how many items will be in the list, sometimes maybe empty.

e.g.

```
{"item_details":[{"id":"123"},{"id":"345"}..],

"student_details":[{"name":"Jason"},{"name":"Jonny"}..]

}
```

I want to get the all the ids and names in the attribute. How to achieve that?

Comment: How do you want to be the results, in which format?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Extract them in the attribute.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to add a sample desired result

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the Jolt Transform Jolt Processor and use a site like https://jsonpath.com/ to get a query that you like. I would use a site like https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception to determine the Jolt that you would want. It can be done to select the values if you know which values could exist.